# CakePHP v3 installation with SLQite, default web app can't find MySQL

Tags: sqlite, cakephp

I'm on a W7 32-bit platform. Following the installation instructions in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html, and using the builtin PHP server. The default web app reports:

> *Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql cannot be used due to a missing PHP extension or unmet dependency*

At this early stage in my cake career, I do not know whether I can rebuild this default app, or how to. I have configured PHP to use PDO-sqlite not MySQL, and used it to write an app which successfully interrogates a SQLite database via PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was looking for the configuration file in the wrong place. The right place is <\my_app>\config\app.php, just change the driver name to that  of the SQLite driver and it all works.